# Angular 2 - my project has no @NgModule({}) or appmodule?

Tags: angular, configuration

I'm at a loss here, and can't find anyone describing this issue.

I have a fully functioning application, but I can't find an @NgModule across the entire codebase, an AppComponent, or anything like that. This makes it impossible for me to use plugins which require an import in @NgModule such as https://github.com/shlomiassaf/angular2-modal.

Where would I find this file, do I have to create it in an existing file (I thought it was a prerequisite for the project to run?), or something else?

I've been floundering on this for a few days now. I see plenty of posts about errors people get when this isn't set up correctly, so it's curious that my app is running without any issues.

Comment: Perhaps you're using an old Angular version <= 2.0.0-RC.5

Comment: Can't imagine Angular without NgModule

Comment: Another option would be that you're using Dart, there also is no `@NgModule()` ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@NgModule()` was introduced with Angular version <= 2.0.0-RC.5 and became mandatory with version <= 2.0.0-RC.6, therefore if you're using an older version, then there can't be an `@NgModule()`